# how to run c#.net windows application in Windows CE platform?

Tags: c#

I have a windows application in c#.net 3.5 framework. I want to run this application on my scanner device that has windows CE . Is there any solution to run my .net application on windows CE 6.0 ? I tried to install Compact framework but it does not work as device has lower memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run a "windows.net" application on windows CE. First of all you should take care about the platform and processor and .net version. Compact versions of .net are lacking most of the methods from major .net versions.

If you want to run a .net application on any platform, you should make a design for it or rewrite the application on the target platform and .net version.

Comment: ok. Thanks . I knew This but i still want to know if there any way . but now i will redesign my app.